# Definir uma ordem especifica na query

Tags: sql

Eu tenho uma query que seleciona todos os membros do grupo por ordem de rank (dono, administrador e membro) e pela data na qual o membro se juntou ao grupo. Pela coluna `access_level` não ser númerica eu não sei como coloco na ordem de rank.

```
SELECT * FROM group_memberships WHERE group_id = ? ORDER BY access_level ASC, STR_TO_DATE(date_joined, '%M %Y') ASC LIMIT;
```

access_level usa o tipo de dados ENUM *owner, administrator e member*, e é exatamente nesta ordem que quero.

Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Utilize a função [`FIELD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field). Ex: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(access_level, 'owner', 'adm', 'member')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Você pode tentar ordenar com um CASE WHEN

ORDER
   BY CASE WHEN access_level = 'owner' THEN 1 
           WHEN access_level = 'administrator' THEN 2
           WHEN access_level = 'member' THEN 3
       END ASC,
STR_TO_DATE(date_joined, '%M %Y') ASC LIMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trazer um campo de ordenação Fictício na sua consulta e ordenar por ele.

```
SELECT IF(access_level="owner",1,IF(access_level = "administrator",2,3))AS Ornedacao
FROM group_memberships ORDER BY Ordenacao
```